# Why would I use prototype.js with scriptaculous.js... What's the main reason?

Tags: javascript, scriptaculous

Why would I want to use prototype.js with scriptaculous.js? What's the main reason?
When would I need both libraries and when wouldn't I?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? The default answer to this would be "it depends" based on the implementation you're looking for and whether either prototype or scriptaculous (or something else like jQuery) could handle the functionality on its own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used prototype for quite some time, and scriptaculous with it ; I now use jQuery on some projects, Mootools on others, and prototype on others...

Why do I use a JS Framework ?

Well, three main reasons :

- They provide lots of stuff I do not want to re-develop by myself
- They are well-tested ; more than my own code would be
- They provide a layer of cross-browser-compatibility (And I prefer having a framework that deals with that, instead of having to fight this war by myself !)

As for which JS Framework you should use, that's another question - it's entirely up to you ^^

When including prototype.js and/or scriptaculous.js :

- prototype.js : on any page that needs some JS stuff (most pages generally)
- scriptaculous.js : at least on pages that require effects like drag'n drop, autocompleter, etc...

Same thing with other JS frameworks too, btw...

Answer (score 6):

Scriptaculous uses Prototype internally.  If you use Scriptaculous, you need Prototype.

Answer (score 1):

The scriptaculous.js file is a helper file which includes the remaining scripts using document.write calls.

As you can see from the code written in the scriptaculous.js file, its including the builder, effects, etc. libraries by calling the `require` function.

```
var Scriptaculous = {
  Version: '1.8.2',
  require: function(libraryName) {
    // inserting via DOM fails in Safari 2.0, so brute force approach
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+libraryName+'"><\/script>');
  },
  REQUIRED_PROTOTYPE: '1.6.0.3',
  load: function() {
    function convertVersionString(versionString) {
      var v = versionString.replace(/_.*|\./g, '');
      v = parseInt(v + '0'.times(4-v.length));
      return versionString.indexOf('_') > -1 ? v-1 : v;
    }

    if((typeof Prototype=='undefined') ||
       (typeof Element == 'undefined') ||
       (typeof Element.Methods=='undefined') ||
       (convertVersionString(Prototype.Version) <
        convertVersionString(Scriptaculous.REQUIRED_PROTOTYPE)))
       throw("script.aculo.us requires the Prototype JavaScript framework >= " +
        Scriptaculous.REQUIRED_PROTOTYPE);

    var js = /scriptaculous\.js(\?.*)?$/ig;
    $$('head script[src]').findAll(function(s) {
      return s.src.match(js);
    }).each(function(s) {
      var path = s.src.replace(js, ''),
      includes = s.src.match(/\?.*load=([a-z,]*)/);
      (includes ? includes[1] : 'builder,effects,drag-drop,controls,slider,sound').split(',').each(
       function(include) { Scriptaculous.require(path+include+'.js') });
    });
  }
};

Scriptaculous.load();
```

And, we include the prototype library because scriptaculous is a kind of add-on based on the prototype library. You can't use scriptaculous without prototype as it calls methods available in the prototype library.

Answer (score 1):

[Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) uses [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), so if you're using any Scriptaculous effects on a page, then you need to include it.

If you can't see any obvious uses of Scriptaculous, its possible you've got other javascript using Prototype, which provides a sort of cross-platform utility layer for writing concise and effective code. A quick way to check for that is to look for javascript including calls to $()